# Are there any fast-rendering game libraries that use "GPU mode" as a rendering method in Air for iOS?

Tags: ios, performance, flash, air, starling-framework

I've been toying around with starling 2D and found out my game runs faster without it. The reason is simply because the game uses lots of vector shapes and "direct" mode is just too slow in rendering shapes. Using GPU mode, FPS went up from 20 to around 55.

There was a small trade off though. Rendering static images such as BitmapData(Textures) was faster with starling 2d. Also I didn't have to worry about whether if my graphic assets are being hardware acceralated or not all the time.

So I'm looking for a game(graphic) library for Air for iOS which works in GPU rendering mode and makes it easier to manage BitmapData Caching.

Does anyone know any?

Comment: No idea, but basically, you should also take care of the image dimensions, some underlying OpenGL profiles (GPU mode?) just support power of two texture dimensions, so this could also be a reason for a slowdown because of tiled rendering or whatever workaround allowing you to draw the bitmap nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It's one of the reasons I wanted to quit using stage3d as managing texture(mainly its size) is tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 render modes that can be selected when you create an AIR application using `<renderMode>mode</renderMode>` in the application.xml file.

`<renderMode>cpu</renderMode>` or `<renderMode>auto</renderMode>` (Using Auto defaults to CPU)

- Everything is rendered in software
- Easiest to build
- Performance improvements can be made with bitmap caching

`<renderMode>gpu</renderMode>`

- Vectors and cached surfaces are rendered through hardware
- Text and vectors can use cacheAsBitmapMatrix
- There are many limitations (read more here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html)

`<renderMode>direct</renderMode>` (aka Stage3D)

- GPU accelerated rendering engine
- Faster than any other rendering technique
- Many useful frameworks such as Starling and Away3D
- Create applications close to native level performance
- Handle most recurring scripts in Event.ENTER_FRAME

It's upto you which you would like to choose. Try to stay away from heavy features such as:

- Bitmap effects (shadow, gloss, emboss…)
- Masks (inherently vector-based)
- Alpha channels
- Blend modes (add, multiply…)
- Embedded fonts (Especially Unicode)
- Complex vector artwork

There are no 2D vector libraries to my knowledge. I recommend exporting your vectors to sprite sheets. I know it doesn't scale as easily but it's the supported way of developing games in AIR.

Dustin

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It would be nice if direct mode's GPU acceleration supported vector drawing but until Adobe do something i guess I have to stick with GPU mode.